# How do I add leading blanks to a Tableau integer

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to manually format Tableau integers so a list will right justify numbers.  There is no LPAD() function.  You can see in the drop-down list where the column of numbers are not alighned.

I've tried using STR(), LEFT(), RIGHT() variations to get this concatenated value to align properly.

You can see from this picture what I'm trying to achieve.  I cannot get the small image to display.

I have a list like this:
 23 some text
 103  some text.

I need the 23 and 103 right aligned so the text will align vertically too

[image]

Comment: You are not formatting a Tableau integer, you are formatting a Tableau *string* that contains an integer. You need to think purely in terms of string processing functions and how they can process particular character sets inside a string. If simple alternatives don't cut it, you could always consider using the *regular expression* functions which enable quite complex pattern recognition in strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an if/else block to handle up to the number of characters you want.  Search (FIND) the first space in your text and depending on where it is, add some extra spaces. Example:

```
IF (FIND([FIELD], " ") = 2) THEN
    "   " + [FIELD]
ELSEIF (FIND([FIELD], " ") = 3) THEN
    "  " + [FIELD]
ELSEIF (FIND([FIELD], " ") = 4) THEN
    " " + [FIELD]
ELSE
    [FIELD]
END
```

*NB:* The solution above is only going to work for the first "word" regardless of whether or not it is numbers.  I'm not sure of a solution specifically for numbers.